# Change the height of a Flutter Listview

Tags: flutter

I want to have a horizontal listview of Containers. It is taking up 100% of the screen height even when I specify a small value of height in the outer container.

```
class Mobile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MobileState createState() => _MobileState();
}

class _MobileState extends State<Mobile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      size: const Size(double.infinity, double.infinity),
      painter: MobilePainter(), 
      child: Container(
        height: 10.0,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 160.0,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 160.0,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 160.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 160.0,
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 160.0,
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MobilePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final height = size.height;
    final width = size.width;
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Color(0xFFF9DA5D);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate != this;
  }
}
```

There is no change when I change the height of the outer container.

Comment: What is the parent of the outer `Container` ?

Comment: It's `CustomPaint`

Comment: Can you share that code?

Answer (score 0):

Put Expanded outside of your "Container"

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities! If its parent forces your Mobile widget to fill the place, you should probably set a custom height on the parent widget.

```
SizedBox(child: Mobile(), height: 50),
```

A widget that can probably solve your issue right now but from which you should not abuse is the UnconstrainedBox; it will remove the parent's constraints and let your child takes the height it desires!

```
UnconstrainedBox(child: Mobile(), height: 50),
```